# django cookies not getting set

Tags: python, django, cookies

i am trying to set django test cookies on homepage but it is not getting set set.I have tried everything from changing middleware classes to sessionengines
my index function

def index(request):

```
request.session.set_test_cookie()
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

here is my other function to test cookie

def register(request):

```
if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
    print ">>>> TEST COOKIE WORKED!"
    request.session.delete_test_cookie()
# Like before, get the request's context.
context = RequestContext(request)

# A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
# Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
registered = False

# If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
    # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    # If the two forms are valid...
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        # Save the user's form data to the database.
        user = user_form.save()

        # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
        # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
        # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
        # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user

        # Did the user provide a profile picture?
        # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.


        # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
        profile.save()

        # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
        registered = True

    # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
    # Print problems to the terminal.
    # They'll also be shown to the user.
    else:
        print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

# Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
# These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

# Render the template depending on the context.
return render_to_response(
        'register.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
        context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to do all those middle ware changes to your settings file. I have just tried setting up a simple demonstration of your code and it works perfect.

First thing, try minimizing your code to only the cookie setting 'experiment'. You can try this demo here.

One one view maybe an index of a home view set the cookie.
On another view maybe an index view of another app test the cookie.

```
  From the docs you can only test using another page request I quote
  *test_cookie_worked()* "Returns either True or False, depending on whether the user’s    
   browser accepted the test cookie. Due to the way cookies work, 
   you’ll have to call set_test_cookie() on a previous, 
   separate page request. See Setting test cookies below for more information."

    project/appxx/views ... request.session.set_test_cookie() #inside a view
    project/appyy/views ...  if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                               request.session.delete_test_cookie()
                               return HttpResponse(">>>> TEST COOKIE WORKED!")
```

Then you can add on the logic later. I have used the **HttResponse** method instead of the print statment you used.